# pass current browser url address to bean

Tags: javascript, jsf

I want to send the browser url address to bean,I found this

```
HttpServletRequest requestObj = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String url = requestObj.getRequestURL();
```

I did not get the right browser address,so I will use javasript `window.location` to get the browser address,but how can I send this to back bean?Every answers will be helpful,any ideas?

Comment: Edit your post and format the code using indentation.. Read the [tour] and [ask] and improve it. And why does it not return the correct url?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap().get("referer")
```

in the back bean, you can have the request url. This bothers me for a long long time, hope this will help someone.